# how to log data into a new file?

Tags: node.js, node.js-fs, appendfile

I'm a beginner to node.js, started to learn just a few days ago. i'm trying to log the listener's data into a new file by using `fs.appendFile`, but no matter how many times i try to change the code, it keeps giving me an `ERR-INVALID-CALLBACK`.

```
const Logger = require('./logger_demo')
const logger = new Logger
const fs = require('fs')
logger.on('message', data => console.log('Called Listener: ', data))
fs.appendFile('./log_demo.js', 'message', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log('File has been appended!')
})

fs.appendFile(logger.log('Hello World!'))
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What exactly you're trying to do with the last line??

fs.appendFile(logger.log('Hello World!'))

Also can you please share the logger file?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsappendfilepath-data-options-callback Check this link

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be here:

```js
const logger = new Logger
```

Should it be this?

```js
const logger = new Logger()
```

Additionally, you need to give a file-path to `fs.appendFile`:

```js
fs.appendFile("log.txt", logger.log('Hello World!'))
```

But I think you meant to do this:

```js
logger.log('Hello World!')
```

Comment: it still shows the same error :( thanks for your answer though!

Comment: @eggyolk I addressed some further issues

Answer (score 0):

```js
fs.appendFile(logger.log('Hello World!'))
```

This line is your problem you are calling `fs.appendFile` with wrong parameters